# Is it possible to alter an electronic system state via non conventional ways?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, waves, electrons, complex-systems

I came across this [xkcd post](http://xkcd.com/378/) which reminded me of the [story of isolated systems](http://waitbutwhy.com/2015/01/artificial-intelligence-revolution-1.html) (no physical internet connection) running artificial superintellligence. Systems which would somehow still be able to influence external systems to behave in ways we wouldn't even suspect. I've always thought we simply aren't there, yet. But the question still applies. Is that physically possible?

Comment: I think this question is really too broad..... but comment that the xkcd cartoon is a reference to the 'butterfly effect', which is a real and yet uncontrollable effect in non-linear systems such as the weather. - A question about the butterfly effect would be more answerable than this I am afraid.

Comment: Also in the xkcd cartoon the bit is flipped by cosmic rays, which are high energy particles from space that penetrate from the upper atmosphere - this means that the system - the magnetic recording device perhaps - is not an isolated system....

Comment: In the butterfly-effect sense, no.  It's not possible because systems with sensitive dependence on initial conditions are *really* sensitive: the amount of computational power you need to simulate the system well enough to do this sort of thing grows stupidly fast with the time you need to predict ahead: fast enough to make exponential growth look fairly slow in many cases.